# PHP minimum distance from one stationary object to multiple objects around it

Tags: php

I am solving an issue where I have object A(lat, lon) with different objects B(lat, lon) C(lat, lon) D(lat, lon) and so on. I would like to compute which one of this objects is the closest to object A. The number of objects are unknown. Can someone give me a hint on how to do this?

```
function minDistance(obj A, obj B, obj C .....){
compute distance between obj A and all the arguments and return the obj  with minimum distance to obj A here(I prefer Haversine)
}
```

Comment: If you can assume to be working with x,y-grid, it's simply the hypothenuse of the right triangle formed between two points. If you need to take into account the curvature of the earth, you need haversine.

Answer (score 0):

How about "the Pythagorean Theorem?"  :-)

Conceptually, each of the pairs of objects ... (A,B), (A,C), (A,D), *et al*, are the hypotenuse-points of a right triangle.  Therefore, the distance between them is given by the Pythagorean Theorem.